# Возможно ли задать запуск Распознавания голоса в определенное время?

Tags: android

Интересует такой вопрос: Можно ли задать запуск распознавания голоса на указанное время, например на 9 часов вечера? Если 'да', то каким образом?

Comment: Предполагаю, что через Alarm Manager можно подобное устроить. Как с будильником - только распознавание голоса.

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно. AlarmManager, TimerTask, Handler. Можно сделать связку Service + Timer. Они очень сильно отличаются и все зависит от желаемого эффекта.